# What's name of this sidebar control in UWP and Windows 8.1?

Tags: windows-phone, win-universal-app, windows-8.1-universal

In Windows 8.1 and Windows 10 app I see this right sidebar in some apps. It's very useful to put Settings on and. When click "Preferences" like in screenshot, it appear in right and override app. 
Anyone can tell me what name of this control and link to any tutorial?

[image: UWP app]

[image: Windows 8.1 app on Windows 10]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That was a Windows 8/8.1 thing as far as I know... it was called SettingsFlyout.  The quickstart is [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh872190).  I do not believe it is available in Windows 10 UWP applications.

Comment: This is answer I need. After few search I know that it still available on UWP app but not recommend

Answer (score 0):

You can use splitview control. Here are the links
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/quick_thoughts/2015/06/01/windows-10-splitview-build-your-first-hamburger-menu/
http://www.wintellect.com/devcenter/jprosise/taming-the-splitview-control-in-windows-10

Comment: I know about SplitView, but I don't think above app using split view. Another example in all Windows 8.1 apps running on Windows 10, always have Settings SideBar (open Menu in Title Bar and click Settings): http://i.imgur.com/cLIo47p.png